# MSAccess: Diff Two Tables?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a task to compare 2 MSAccess tables.  They are identical in structure coming from 2 consecutive exports from a 3rd party data source, 1 month apart (n and n+1).  10K records, 35 fields.

I don't necessarily need to know which field(s) have been updated, just that something has changed within a record.  My process will then continue to handle to the delta records accordingly in the destination DB.

I already ID the Inserts and Deletes in the n+1 data.  This will be a monthly exercise.

Any suggestions to begin this task?  I would prefer not to compare field-by-field, row-by-row.  Maybe something equivalent to a ~checksum?

Thank you!

Comment: Because of the way databases work, you inherently can't calculate a checksum of a table since the table might contain fragmented pages/uncommitted data/etc. You can, of course, export to a format that doesn't have these issues/features and calculate a checksum on the exported file.

Comment: Erik, not a traditional checksum per se, rather some other approach to use to pre-compute to compare to detect record containing a change.   Gross example:  concatenate all the field values for a record into a memo field and compare that long string to the prior long string for mismatches...

Comment: Note - one of the 35 fields is already a memo field, so above thought may not be valid.

Comment: Honestly, that's just slower than comparing row-by-row, field-by-field. I've used code doing that on 10K-record tables that finished within minutes. Memo fields can slow it down, though.

Comment: Do note that ADODB recordsets do offer a `.GetString` method to cast the entire recordset to a formatted string, but this _will_ cause overhead when using a table with mainly numerical types, because 1. numerical types cast to a string cost more storage space, 2. it can't fail ahead-of-time, both recordsets need to be fully loaded into memory, 3. it requires allocating and comparing 2 very large strings. I doubt it'll be faster than row-by-row field-by-field comparing, but it's certainly easier to write.

Comment: Erik, I'll try stepping thru the 2 tables field-by-field, row-by-row to measure performance.  This might be worth the effort anyway...  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the suggestion of Erik (above), I can confirm stepping thru the tables field-by-field, row-by-row and performing the compare is pretty quick.  10K rows x 33 fields = ~1-2 sec.

One adjustment I needed to make was to account for inserted or missing rows in either the n or n+1 tables.  I simply JOINED the 2 tables on [ID], eliminating any misalignments, then stepped thru the resulting record set, comparing the pairs of columns.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim n, i, j As Integer

' Join the 2 tables into a single recordset, side-by-side

strSQL = "SELECT TestData.*, TestData2.* FROM TestData " & _
    "INNER JOIN TestData2 ON TestData.[ID] = TestData2.[ID];"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'column-by-column, row-by-row, compare pairs of columns

n = rs.Fields.Count / 2

For i = 0 To n-1
    j = i + n
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        While (Not rs.EOF)
            If Not (Nz(rs.Fields(i)) = Nz(rs.Fields(j))) Then
               Debug.Print "ID " & rs.Fields(0) & " | " & rs.Fields(i).Name & " | " & rs.Fields(i) & " <> " & rs.Fields(j)
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    rs.MoveFirst
Next i

MsgBox "all done"

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```